# On the set of indices of irreducible depth 3 subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, planar-algebras

Let $I_n$ be the set of indices of (finite index) irreducible depth $n$ subfactors. Then $I_2 = \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.

*Question 1:* Is it true that $I_3$ has no accumulation point?

If so:
*Question 2:* Is it true that $|I_3 \cap [x-1,x]|\le x$ (for $x$ large enough)?

If so, let $\epsilon_n$ be the infimum of the length of the gaps in $I_n$ (obviously, $\epsilon_2 = 1$), i.e. 
$$\epsilon_n := \inf \{ |a-b| \text{ such that } a,b \in I_n \text{ and } a \neq b \}. $$

*Question 3:* Is it true that $\epsilon_3>0$?

*Guess*: Q1 yes, Q2 yes and Q3 no. Same questions at depth $n > 3$?