# What do you like in the mathematics of Vaughan Jones? And how Vaughan Jones liked mathematics to be?

Tags: soft-question, oa.operator-algebras, ho.history-overview

**Edit:** Directed to mathematicians ,I think this is a suitable time to open this question to know more about the creative mathematician  **Vaughan Jones** Probably his students are ready for getting answers from them right now .

From  [Terry Tao's Blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/09/09/vaughan-jones/#comments), [Vaughan Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaughan_Jones), who made fundamental contributions in operator algebras and knot theory (in particular developing a surprising connection between the two), [died this week](https://news.vanderbilt.edu/2020/09/09/vaughan-jones-preeminent-vanderbilt-mathematician-has-died/), aged 67.

**Vaughan Jones was a very creative mathematician and he was arguably an extreme point in the convex hull of all mathematicians. He will very much be missed. And as a  scientific family from MO we extend our sincere condolences to his family, friends and students.**

And here is my big list/simple question to know more about this creative mathematician is:

> **Question:**  What do you like in the mathematics of Vaughan Jones? and how Vaughan Jones liked mathematics to be ?

Addendum: This part is directed to his students and his colleagues. As Jon Bannon suggested and pointed out in the comments, since Vaughan Jones was a very creative mathematician we may get from Vaughan Jones' students or by his colleagues the state of the art of his vision? And how Vaughan Jones saw what the applications of planar algebra in Quantum theory should be? The best example is [the reformulation of Riemann hypothesis using planar algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308300/51189). More than that, how Vaughan Jones saw the connection between planar algebra and number theory should be used to solve biggest open problems in pure mathematics like Riemann hypothesis and irrationality measure of pi? Also from the point of view of Vaughan Jones does the expedition growth of mathematics need more development of knot theory and its connection with other area of mathematics and physics?

Comment: His known results are pretty famous.  In terms of 'unpublished results', I'm not sure, but Tao already mentions a good one in the blog post you have linked to.

Comment: @Tao said in the linked post " I have not had much occasion to directly use much of Vaughan’s mathematical contributions"

Comment: Dear Zeraoulia: Just a suggestion. Vaughan was a very creative mathematician. I would love to have a question asking about the state of the art of his vision/ the things he would like to have seen accomplished. Maybe some of his students or close colleagues might be able to provide some of these things on MO for future activity. For example, his theory of planar algebras may point to things many of us are unaware of...in any case, Jones will be sorely missed.

Comment: In my last year of high school (12th grade), I took a couple of classes at UC Berkeley, including discrete math and proofs (mostly for computer science students) taught by Vaughan Jones. That was a great class!

Comment: @John Bannon , I already what you have suggested to me , I wish that I covred your needs

Comment: A meta discussion about memorial questions is here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4619/ron-graham-1935-2020-and-mo-memorial-questions

Comment: This is asking about Jones’s lesser results, Jones’s known results, Jones’s vision for quantum theory and Jones’s vision for number theory — so I have voted to close for lack of focus. I would prefer a simpler big-list question, “what do you like in the mathematics of Vaughan Jones?”

Comment: I agree with Matt F. "Lesser-known results" worked very well for John H. Conway but I don't think it works equally well for all mathematicians, and I don't think that every time a famous mathematician dies, there should automatically be an MO question asking for lesser-known results.

Comment: @TimothyChow, An MO question about every mathematician dies  offer students and paople aknowldgemnts and checking his area of reasearch encourage  students for research , The  nice thing I saw in the blog of Terry Tao always share contributions and information about new died mathematician

Comment: @zeraouliarafik : Even if I accept everything you say in this last comment, it does not justify the title "Lesser-known results."

Comment: @TimothyChow, I agree with you I have edited the question turning it big list simple question to avoid iteration of this question in MO

Comment: It would be nice of people were not doing these knee-jerk reflex "close" votes on such questions; we have nothing to lose by learning about a mathematician's works and if someone in the community decides to honor them like this, then why not? why be so uptight and caught up in own self-importance to strike with your "close" hammers, being a bit more gracious for such instances only makes you more human.

Comment: This question feels...premature.  There will come a day when it's time to write about Jones' mathematical contributions, but for most of his students and colleagues, he was a friend and news of his death was a shock.  (It's possible that some of them learned about his death from this MO post.)  Most of the people who could answer this question well are busy processing grief right now, and it feels a bit ghoulish to request that they amuse us by filling in answers to a big list question.  Right now, I think this question falls afoul of Paul Siegel's 'tasteful' criterion.

Comment: @user1504  Really am confused and am sorry in the same time for  mathematicians who they are voted to close this question, I think it is very appropriate to MO website  to ask about advices or recomondation of mathematician who spent his life to serve scientific life and particulary mathematics  .

Comment: I have to agree in a sense that this is a bit jarring to see such a question so quickly. I'm even still mourning another mathematician's passing and never found it fitting to compose a memorial question for him. I tried to write a reflective piece to deal with it, but stalled and hope one day to do so well. There is, though, a desire/impulse to immediately pay one's respects or deal with the grief by posting or writing something...even right away. It may feel as if one can hold onto the experience of hearing a mathematician's ideas one final time as a farewell.

Comment: @JonBannon, I think it is the suitable time for this question to be open because opening this question means encourage  students and researchers to  get benefits and acknowledgement about knot theory and planar algebera .

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik: The idea of encouraging students and researchers getting benefits and acknowledgements from the work of a recently deceased mathematician makes such students and researchers somewhat like a pack of hyenas. I think this is precisely the point. A good question here should celebrate the life and work of the mathematician, and early on the loss is a bit fresh to do so without it seeming a bit grotesque.

Comment: You used to bump the question by repeated edits. I hope you wont do again such a series of repeated edits. In addition I believe that the choice of the questions in the title is particularly poor and awkward.

Comment: Thanks Ycor , I think I will ask another with other reformulation

Comment: Your previous edits already include several attempts... You might also consider waiting until somebody else asks such a question.